# Should I be using UTC time with enableSnapshots

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I wish to edit the snapshot schedule to 'now + 2 minutes'. 
Here is the sample snippet of what I am doing -

```
t_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
sType='WEEKLY'
retention=2
t_new = (t_now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=2))
n_min = t_new.time().minute
n_hr = t_new.time().hour
n_day = t_new.strftime("%A")

result = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage'].enableSnapshots(sType, retention,n_min, n_hr, n_day, id=storageId)
```

So the question is -
For t_now, should I be using UTC time or Central time?

I see that if I use UTC time, then the end result of changed schedule is 6 hrs 2 min past the current time. Hence the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The datetime that you see in the https://control.softlayer.com/ comes down to the timezone configuration of your Softlayer user, Each user has the his own timezone, you can see that in the details of each user (Go users-> click on the user you want). So the datetime that your are using in your code must have the same timezone as your user in softlayer portal. Note: that the timezone of your computer and your user in softlayer may be differents.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your response. So that explains the scheduled time 'shown' by the portal.

But what about 'setting' the schedule via API? Am I right in using UTC time values when I calculate 'now + 2 min' ? Or should I set 'now' to the user's timezone first, as that might change the values for day, hour, minute that I would end up passing to enableSnapshots()

Comment: your datetime must be the same as the user in the portal